# 16.04 LTS not letting me update, says “Not enough free disk space” (Updated 6/18/2018)

Tags: 16.04, updates, disk, disk-usage

I switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu Unity 16.04 LTS on January 1st 2018 (I had to completely erase my Windows OS in order to get Linux on, there wasn't a dual-boot option)

Whenever I log in it shows me 5 pop-ups saying "Error" on them and whenever I try doing a new update it says "Package operation failed - The installation or removal of a software package failed." or "The application Software Updater has closed unexpectedly."

I also need to mention that my network is currently hacked by an IT member (which is why I'm using Linux) and it's not something I can fix at this moment (if this information helps diagnose the problems with my PC)

Here are screenshots of the variety of error messages I'm now getting these days:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**The Updated Part** It gave me this error: Quote on quote: "apt-get -f install" I tried doing that "apt-get -f install" thing the terminal recommended but it gave me another error.

[image]

Here's what happens when I try doing the "apt-get -f install" thing it's telling me to do: "Unmet dependencies" and "Permission denied" from removing old kernels.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GboKo.png]

I tried following the other guides but I was the only one to have this particular issue so my issue is different from the others.

"Can you update your question with the results of ll /boot. Don't use a screenshot, simply copy the text to the clipboard then paste it into your question. – WinEunuuchs2Unix Jun 4 at 10:58"

```
linux@userr:~$ ll /boot
total 128906
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     3072 May 22 18:51 ./
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root     4096 May 12 13:39 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1501416 Apr  5 12:01 abi-4.13.0-39-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1501416 May  3 06:07 abi-4.13.0-41-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   213220 Apr  5 12:01 config-4.13.0-39-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   213220 May  3 06:07 config-4.13.0-41-generic
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     1024 May 22 18:49 grub/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 52136654 May 19 13:42 initrd.img-4.13.0-39-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 52137886 May 22 18:51 initrd.img-4.13.0-41-generic
drwx------  2 root root    12288 Jan  3 13:47 lost+found/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      255 Apr  5 12:01 retpoline-4.13.0-39-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      255 May  3 06:07 retpoline-4.13.0-41-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3882732 Apr  5 12:01 System.map-4.13.0-39-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3882700 May  3 06:07 System.map-4.13.0-41-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7712016 Apr  5 12:01 vmlinuz-4.13.0-39-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7711664 May  3 06:07 vmlinuz-4.13.0-41-generic
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the results of `ll /boot`. Don't use a screenshot, simply copy the text to the clipboard then paste it into your question.

Comment: You need to preface the apt-get -f install with sudo and enter your password when prompted.

Comment: You can use `sudo apt clean` or `sudo apt autoclean` to clear all package archives to free up some space for downloading the packages.